# MySQL select unique rows in two columns with the highest value in one column

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a basic table:

```
+-----+--------+------+------+
| id, | name,  | cat, | time |
+-----+--------+------+------+
|   1 | jamie  |    1 |  100 |
|   2 | jamie  |    2 |  100 |
|   3 | jamie  |    1 |   50 |
|   4 | jamie  |    2 |  150 |
|   5 | bob    |    1 |  100 |
|   6 | tim    |    1 |  300 |
|   7 | alice  |    4 |  100 |
+-----+--------+------+------+
```

I tried using the "Left Joining with self, tweaking join conditions and filters" part of this answer: [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column/7745635#7745635) but some reason when there are records with a value of 0 it breaks, and it also doesn't return every unique answer for some reason.

When doing the query on this table I'd like to receive the following values:

```
+-----+--------+------+------+
| id, | name,  | cat, | time |
+-----+--------+------+------+
|   1 | jamie  |    1 |  100 |
|   4 | jamie  |    2 |  150 |
|   5 | bob    |    1 |  100 |
|   6 | tim    |    1 |  300 |
|   7 | alice  |    4 |  100 |
+-----+--------+------+------+
```

Because they are unique on name and cat and have the highest time value.

The query I adapted from the answer above is:

```
SELECT a.name, a.cat, a.id, a.time
FROM data A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT name, cat, id, MAX(time) as time
    FROM data
    WHERE extra_column = 1
    GROUP BY name, cat
) b ON a.id = b.id AND a.time = b.time
```

Comment: Don't join on ID.  Join on name and cat. and time  to get ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that ID is unique per row you can't get the unique value when getting the max; you have to join on the grouped values instead.

```
SELECT a.name, a.cat, a.id, a.time
FROM data A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT name, cat, MAX(time) as time
    FROM data
    WHERE extra_column = 1
    GROUP BY name, cat
) b ON A.Cat = B.cat and A.Name = B.Name AND a.time = b.time
```

Think about it... So what ID is mySQL returning form the Inline view?  It could be 1 or 3 and 2 or 4 for jamie.  Hows does the engine know to pick the one with the max ID?  it is "free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. "  it could pick the wrong one resulting in incorrect results.  So you can't use it to join on.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: This looks correct to me.  For some understanding of where you went wrong, read the link below.  Basically, MySQL should never have let your inner query run, but it did, and its by design:   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

--Edit:  I see xQbert thought to add the same note :)

Comment: Resolve incident first, then improve upon the answer :P as to Why it's correct :P

Comment: Thank you very much - that's brilliant. All working now :) (gotta wait 3 mins before I can mark it correct)

Comment: @JamieH be sure to check out fthiella's as well.   It's a different approach but yields the same results and may be better performance depending on data volume and indexes!

Comment: Cheers - If I hit any performance problems with this solution then I'll give that one ago :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a self join, you could use this query:

```
SELECT
  d1.*
FROM
  date d1 LEFT JOIN date d2
  ON d1.name=d2.name
     AND d1.cat=d2.cat
     AND d1.time<d2.time
WHERE
  d2.time IS NULL
```

Comment: Just curious... if more than 2 times existed per name and cat... would this return more than 1 record per name/cat?  never mind no it wouldn't that's what the is null where clause is for.

Comment: @xQbert I was also checking, depend if they have ties on the max time.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza that wouldn't be an issue due to d1.time<d2.time... they can't equal.  It's elegant I like it!

Comment: @xQbert Exactly, so both will have null, and both will appear on result. You ask if can return more than one result

Comment: Ah true; but nothing a group by wouldn't solve.  and this offers flexibility if you want/need both.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple

> SELECT MAX(TIME),name,cat FROM `table name` group by cat